# Compare 2 floats by their bitwise representation in C

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, unsigned, ieee

I had this question on my exam, and I couldn't realy solve it, will appreciate some help.

> Fill the blanks only, function must return true if and only if x<y.
> Assume x,y cannot be NaN (but can be +-inf) no casting is allowed, use only ux, uy, sx, sy

```
bool func(float x, float y) {
    unsigned* uxp = ______________ ;
    unsigned* uyp = ______________ ;
    unsigned  ux  = *uxp;
    unsigned  uy  = *uyp;
    unsigned  sx = (ux>>31); 
    unsigned  sy = (uy>>31);
    return ___________________________;
}
```

Comment: The first two blanks should be filled by casting the addresses of the parameters to the same type as `uxp` and `uyp`.

Comment: This function is invalid. Invokes Undefined Behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rules. Your teacher needs to learn

Comment: Dosent &x , &y are enough? And then uxp and uyp are 2 pointers to an unsigned integer.

Comment: Nope.  Strict aliasing means the only "wrong" type you can use is char.  You very definitely can't use pointer to type-pun a float to an unsigned int.  See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650)

Comment: @SteveSummit compiler disagrees https://godbolt.org/z/hWPaGnvdW

Comment: @0___________ Compiler disagrees with what/who? I was replying to MultiHunter's question about "&x , &y are enough", and agreeing with you that strict aliasing was violated!

Comment: MultiHunter, `+0.0f == -0.0f`.  Should `func()` compare them as the same value or different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the assignment assumes `float` uses IEEE-754 binary32 and `unsigned` is 32 bits.

It is not proper to alias `float` objects with an `unsigned` type, although some C implementations support it. Instead, you can create a compound literal union, initialize its `float` member with the `float` value, and access its `unsigned` member. (This is supported by the C standard but not by C++.)

After that, it is simply a matter of dividing the comparison into cases depending on the sign bits:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool func(float x, float y) {
    unsigned* uxp = & (union { float f; unsigned u; }) {x} .u;
    unsigned* uyp = & (union { float f; unsigned u; }) {y} .u;
    unsigned  ux  = *uxp;
    unsigned  uy  = *uyp;
    unsigned  sx = (ux>>31); 
    unsigned  sy = (uy>>31);
    return
         sx &&  sy ? uy < ux :  // Negative values are in "reverse" order.
         sx && !sy ? (uy | ux) & 0x7fffffffu : // Negative x is always less than positive y except for x = -0 and y = +0.
        !sx &&  sy ?    0    :  // Positive x is never less than negative y.
                     ux < uy ;  // Positive values are in "normal" order.
}


#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    // Print expected values and function values for comparison.
    printf("1, %d\n", func(+3, +4));
    printf("1, %d\n", func(-3, +4));
    printf("0, %d\n", func(+3, -4));
    printf("0, %d\n", func(-3, -4));
    printf("0, %d\n", func(+4, +3));
    printf("1, %d\n", func(-4, +3));
    printf("0, %d\n", func(+4, -3));
    printf("1, %d\n", func(-4, -3));
}
```

Sample output:

```
1, 1
1, 1
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
1, 1
0, 0
1, 1
```

Comment: Quite poetic code you have here for `return ___________________________`.

Comment: thanks!! first of all I had no idea about strict aliasing rules and that they can lead to an undefined behaviour. although to be honest even after reading about it im not sure what can happend if i'll defined uxp and uyp like this:
`code` unsigned* uxp = (unsigned*)&x; `code` . anyways the answer of Eric Postpischil realy helped thanks!!